Discrepancy in EDGAR data
My question is about the source of truth regarding EDGAR.
I am developing a simple service for myself to choose stocks based on fundamental data. Therefore I went to the EDGAR site and downloaded all company facts. Testing I realize that there are discrepancies between the json and the xbrl viewer:

json example: CIK0000001750
xbrl viewer

As an specific example, let's take the account CostOfGoodsAndServicesSold. What I do is separate statements into annual and quarterly. So, reading annual data, the json from EDGAR (above) only provides this (quarterly is slightly better but also not complete):
 {
              "start": "2018-06-01",
              "end": "2019-05-31",
              "val": 1722300000,
              "accn": "0001047469-19-004266",
              "fy": 2019,
              "fp": "FY",
              "form": "10-K",
              "filed": "2019-07-18",
              "frame": "CY2018"
            },

Ok, so I say, let's see how other site calculates it. And I see they take it from the xbrl link (above) which does have the data (900 + 902.8) which is not present in the json:

So basically, I'm blocked at the moment. I see the filings have more complete data than the json submissions and my questions are:

can I get the complete data? If so, how?
is there a better way or API than getting the json directly out of
EDGAR?


This is the code that would obtain the facts with the Brel engine (disclaimer: built by us at ETH as an academic project):
from brel import Filing
from brel.utils import open_edgar, pprint

#load the filing
filing = open_edgar(cik="1750", filing_type="10-K", date="2022-05-31")
#get the concept
CostOfGoodsAndServicesSold = filing.get_concept("us-gaap:CostOfGoodsAndServicesSold")
#get all the facts associated with this concept
facts = filing.get_facts_by_concept(CostOfGoodsAndServicesSold)
#tabular display to a human (note that the API also allows processing with code)
pprint(facts)

This is the output (obtained with a Jupyter Lab notebook with the above code):

You can see that this returns the six facts corresponding to your screenshot, and containing the correct dimensional characteristics.
Brel can be installed with
pip install brel-xbrl

Brel is a processor that respects Edgar Codd's data independence principle. We strive to make it independent from the underlying syntax used (whether XML, JSON, Inline XBRL, CSV...) to shield the user from physical details and stick to the XBRL data model.

Thanks! I'll take a look at it.
Then I have 2 questions: why is that there is data not present in the json and the second is related: the source of truth are actually the filings, right?

You are welcome! 1. The JSON in your link only contains metadata (the list of all filings). There may be other parts of the EDGAR API that return the fact values, but I am not sure how complex it is (i.e., if the contexts are resolved or not).
2. Yes, the source of truth is the filings, XML for the older ones, Inline XBRL for newer ones. However, there are also multiple syntaxes for filings including JSON and CSV and one can convert back and forth between syntaxes. For example, the Inline XBRL filing is automatically converted to an XML filing by EDGAR and both are made available.

The Brel engine directly downloads the XML filings and takes the data from them. It is not recommended to attempt reading the filings directly as XML because of the complexity of the syntax. An XBRL processor is more adequate, in the same way that people use Excel and do not directly open the .xslx files as XML.
